Cannot view webpage that is being hosted by localhost
I have created a webpage using react and node.js. After completing the webpage, I was able to view it initially but from a day later, i have been getting this error
ERROR.
I have tried different methods using ai and have got it working again. But today, i am getting the same error again.
I tried by re-installing the packages and re-building the project. I use vscode and am using 'npm run dev' to run the webpage and i also have live server plugin turned on.
Edit:
Code
I have attached my index.tsx file above which has been showing as error. The error being:
" Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isFeatureEnabled')
at chromewebdata/:1919:49 "
Edit(2):
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

This is the changed index.tsx file, but I am still getting the same error. I have also noticed that when i run npm start, i can get the webpage on port 3000, but it loses its styles and is only a basic webpage.

Please include the code in text form instead of an image

The only thing that comes to my mind is that you need to check if the port has been changed by another one after running npm run dev successfully

Hello, I have checked if the port has chnaged but node is still running in the same port as the one that npm run dev gives

In the question is not provided if you are running a node server for backend and another for front, if that is the case you need to run both separately in different ports and in the browser use the front end project port.

Related to your edited question (the index error) the error points out that you have an object and you're trying to access that property that doesn't exist, try to find where is the object created and if it has that property at that time
I mean as you are passing a function is very weird that the error says cannot read property of undefined

I have also tried to run the code by removing all the "isFeatureEnabled: and tried to run it for errors, but it still shows the same error as the one attached in the question.
